# Binding object within object properties into a WPF Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have two classes, Player and Scorecard. Scorecard has a number of properties,  Player also has properties, one of which is a Scorecard object. I then have an array of Players. How do I setup a WPF Datagrid to display a player on each row with Player’s Name property in the first column but the properties from Player’s Scorecard object in the other rows?

Here are the classes...

```
class Scorecard
    {
        public Scorecard()
        {           
        }

        // Properties
        public int Horses { get; set; } = -1;
        public int Sheep { get; set; } = -1;
        public int Cows { get; set; } = -1;
    }

class Player
    {
        public Player(int playerId, string playerName)
        {
            ID = playerId;
            Name = playerName;
            Scorecard = new Scorecard();
        }

        // Parameters
        public int ID { get; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public Scorecard Scorecard;
    }
```

and this is what I’m hoping to achieve (excuse the ASCII graphics, I don't have enough reputation points to post an image!)...

```
| Name   | Horses | Sheep | Cows  |
| Pete   | 12     | 2     | 4     |
| Lucy   | 2      | 8     | 14    |
```

I’ve searched around and can’t find a solution that’s quite right. The code below gets me the first column but it’s digging into the associated Scorecard object that I can’t work out.

```
        var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
        var binding = new Binding("Name");
        col.Binding = binding;
        dgScoreGrid.Columns.Add(col);
        dgScoreGrid.ItemsSource = playerArray;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st thing is to make Scorecard a *property* (not *field*)

```
// Parameters
// ...
public Scorecard Scorecard { get; }
```

and than according to [Binding Path Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752300(v=vs.100).aspx#Path_Syntax), subproperties of a property can be specified by a similar syntax as in C#.

```
var col = new DataGridTextColumn();
var binding = new Binding("Name");
col.Binding = binding;
dgScoreGrid.Columns.Add(col);

dgScoreGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn{Binding = new Binding("Scorecard.Horses")});

dgScoreGrid.ItemsSource = playerArray;
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's done the trick. I'd actually tried that syntax but hadn't realised that it only applies to properties, not fields.